# Is possible to draw graphics with a function or any function?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let us want to draw a function **y=x^3(the first figue)** and **y=x^4(the second figure)**,, like graphics this following and i use Microsoft mathematics to draw it.

[image: Graph y= x^3]
[image: y=x^4]

Comment: See the documentation of `pgfplots`: `texdoc pgfplots`

Comment: pgfplots ,, ya thank  but  how to draw graph **y =x^2** in 2D ?? Thank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can be done very easily using [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), once you have parametrized the surface

```
x(t,s)=t
y(t,s)=t^3
z(t,s)=s
```

Note that because of the syntax that `pgfplots` uses, I have used

```
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,samples=20,]({x},{x^3},{y});
```

in the code below; `x` represents `t`, and `y` represents `s`.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true, trace: true}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,samples=20,]({x},{x^3},{y});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it can also be done with `pstricks`- I assume the 'bug buster' will post it soon enough :)

Comment: Yes ,, your true ,, and how to draw 2D ,, example **y= x^2** with LaTeX ...

Comment: @HirWanto Instead of the `\addplot3` line, e.g. `\addplot {x^2};` Take a look at [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), there are many examples.